# Loading an Image in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to load an image in JavaFX using it's `Image` class.

Here is my code:

```
Image image = new Image(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

`file` is just a file loading the image.

I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found

Here's the full code:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG","*.jpg"),
        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPEG","*.jpeg")
);
fileChooser.setTitle("Choose file...");
fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(
        new File(System.getProperty("user.home"))
);
File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stageOfEvent);

if(file != null) {
    Image image = new Image(file.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView.setImage(image);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to construct an [`Image`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) with a file located in the filesystem, you need to use the `file:` protocol, like this:

```
Image image = new Image("file:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Not specifying it tells JavaFX to look for the image in the classpath, rather than in the filesystem.

Quoting the Image Javadoc:

> ```
> // The image is located in my.res package of the classpath
> Image image2 = new Image("my/res/flower.png", 100, 150, false, false);
>
> // The image is located in the current working directory
> Image image4 = new Image("file:flower.png", 0, 100, false, false);
> ```

This construct comes from the [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String-) syntax of Java.

As noted by @mipa in the comments, you can also use:

```
Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

Comment: is this platform independent?

Comment: @TrtTrt Why do you think so? No it is not.

Comment: _Why_ would you want to make your code platform dependent??

Comment: my code , is platform independent, I want to make this part platform independent

Comment: @TrtTrt Sorry, I misread your question, the code in my answer is platform-independent.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`ImageIO.read(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-) instead.

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
```